# Backbone.js and Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, railscasts

I just watched the backbone.js railscasts and Im not getting the error alert when the name is not present but do get an error on the server side.

im using rails 3.2.8 and backbone-on-rails 0.9.2.3

In the network console it does state that theres an error with the api/entries, and in the response theres the errors key, but still no alert when I click add with nothing on the form.

This is my code... please help me figure out what could be wrong!

```
class Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['entries/index']

  events:
    'submit #new_entry': 'createEntry'
    'click #draw': 'drawWinner'

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render)
    @collection.on('add', @appendEntry)

  render: =>
    $(@el).html(@template())
    @collection.each(@appendEntry)
    this

  appendEntry: (entry) =>
    view = new Raffler.Views.Entry(model: entry)
    @$('#entries').append(view.render().el)

  drawWinner: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @collection.drawWinner()

  createEntry: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    attributes = name: $('#new_entry_name').val()
    @collection.create attributes,
      wait: true
      success: -> $('#new_entry')[0].reset()
      error: @handleError

    handleError: (entry, response) ->
      if response.status == 422
        errors = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).errors
        for attribute, messages of errors
          alert "#{attribute} #{message}" for message in messages
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong so you don't have a `@handleError`, instead your `createEntry` method is returning an object like this:

```
{ handleError: (entry, response) -> ... }
```

So when you try to use `@handleError` as an error callback:

```
@collection.create attributes,
  wait: true
  success: -> ...
  error: @handleError # <----------- Here
```

you're really saying:

```
@collection.create attributes,
  wait: true
  success: -> ...
  error: undefined
```

and setting your error callback to `undefined` doesn't do anything useful.

Pull `handleError` back towards the left margin two spaces and you might have better luck.